# SSLhandshakeException in Jmeter:Recevied fatal alert:certificate_unknown

Tags: android, jmeter

I am getting

> SSLhandshakeException in Jmeter:Recevied  fatal alert:certificate_unknown

while using jmeter 3.2 for mobile testing.

I want load test for Android app configure with jmeter, any interaction with app leads to this exception.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dWyKu.png)

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you need to import JMeter's self-signed certificate onto your mobile device.

1. Locate `ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt` file under JMeter's bin folder
2. Transfer it to your mobile device somehow (i.e. send it to yourself by email and open the attachment on the mobile device)
3. Follow Android dialog to get it installed

See **HTTPS recording and certificates** chapter of the [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html) manual

Also be aware that you can use an [alternative mobile recording solution](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207420545-BlazeMeter-Proxy-Recorder-Mobile-and-web-#mobile), in that case you won't have to worry about certificates. Also you will have possibility to export recorded script in "SmartJMX" mode with automated correlation of dynamic parameters, see

Comment: Thank You so much, adding certificate on mobile worked for me